# RSS feed returning plain text instead of HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to extract content from [this feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/a_beautiful_mess). This is the code I am using:

```
$rss  = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($feed_url);

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
   $description = $node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   echo $description;
}
```

This however, instead of echoing HTML echoes plain text. Here is the strucutre of feed.

```
<entry>
<title>.....</title>
<link rel=".." type="..." href="...." />
...... More tags ......
<content type="xhtml" xml:lang="en-US"  xml:base="http://www.abeautifulmess.com/">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> HTML is all here.
  </div>
</content>
```

It has not happened with any other feed. Is it because of type of content or something else?

Comment: Have you verified that the feed is valid? Perhaps the feed has an xml error or something.

Comment: If there was an error I think feedburner would have pointed it out. Am I wrong about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DOMDocument::saveHTML` will preserve the html formatting of the node. This will give you what you want:

```
$feed_url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/a_beautiful_mess?format=xml';
$rss  = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($feed_url);

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
   $description = $node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0);
   echo $rss->saveHTML($description);
}
```

Comment: @ElefantPhance thanks. It worked. I have one question though. Is there something different about this feed that I need to use `DOMDocument::saveHTML` to preserve HTML while every other feeds displayed HTML correctly without it?